# How to stop Deepstream Python AppScript Safely?

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano, deepstream

I am running Deepstream 6.0 App with python Bindings on Jetson Nano 4gb with Jetpack 4.6,
the app is able to run the script available [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/tree/master/apps/deepstream-test1-usbcam), How to safely stop/quit the app on terminal, CTRL+Z stops the process without cleaning the deepstream pipeline , CTRL+C is not working, is there any alternate solution to it?

I tried creating a keyboard interuptt with signal packages, it doesn't help.

```
import argparse
import sys
import signal
import os
import cv2
import Jetson.GPIO as GPIO  # Import the GPIO library

# ... (rest of your code) ...

def stop_and_cleanup(pipeline):
    print("Stopping and cleaning up...")
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    loop.quit()  # Quit the GMainLoop
    GPIO.cleanup()  # Cleanup GPIO pins

# ... (rest of your code) ...

def gpio_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel) == GPIO.LOW:
        stop_and_cleanup(pipeline)  # Call the stop_and_cleanup function when pin is grounded

# ... (rest of your code) ...
```

i have used a interuppt signal from gpio, signal is recieved within the script, but it doesnt halt the pipeline

Comment: you can try sending a SIGTERM signal to the process

Comment: sigterm stops the script,but the camera component is not freed

Comment: I AM mentioning the code below try this if its work

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
import sys
import signal
import os
import cv2
import Jetson.GPIO as GPIO

def stop_and_cleanup(pipeline):
    print("Stopping and cleaning up")
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sys.exit(0)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping")
    stop_and_cleanup(pipeline)

def gpio_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel) == GPIO.LOW:
        stop_and_cleanup(pipeline)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)


try:
    loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stop_and_cleanup(pipeline)
```